# router_1.provideRouter is not a function when trying to run Angular2/NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

I have created a simple NodeJS/Angular2 application which is encountering the following error when I try and access the entry point page for the application:

```
router_1.provideRouter is not a function
```

I am unsure as to what this error means and have no idea where to start. Does anyone have any insight or idea as to why this may be happening? Here is my package.json file (as I am thinking it may be something to do with one of the Angular packages)

```
{
  "name": "udemy-nodejs-angular2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently tsc -w &&  nodemon ./bin/www",
    "vendor": "gulp vendor",
    "gulp": "npm run vendor && gulp",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "hbs": "~3.1.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.2",
    "typings": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

and my SystemJS config:

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app': 'js/app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs': 'js/vendor/rxjs',
    '@angular': 'js/vendor/@angular'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app': {main: 'boot.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
};

var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade'
];

// add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'};
});

var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
};

System.config(config);
```

Here are the places I am using the router functionality:

app.routes.ts

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';

import {LoginComponent} from "./components/login/login.component";
import {DashboardComponent} from "./components/dashboard/dashboard.component";


export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

boot.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.template.html',
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
    ]
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you please add your systemjs configuration? This is most likely a missing config for the `@angular/router`-package

Comment: I forget to ask for the code where you use the `provideRouter` function

Comment: Sure I have added my SystemJS config into the original question

Comment: Also the place where the error is thrown is in the index.html file on the line where the SystemJS entry point is created. <script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err);  });
</script>

Comment: I assume that you have something like a `router.config`-file, where you try to use the `routerProvide()`. Can also please add this code-part?

Comment: No worries. I have added the boot.ts (entry point for angular with router instantiation), the routes.ts file (where I define my routes) and the app.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116776/discussion-between-dinistro-and-devoncrazylegs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found out in the chat, the problem was that the router in the vendor folder didn't get updated to the new version.

To solve this problem, the router under the vendor folder must be deleted, then and npm install should be run and finally a npm run gulp recreated the vendor folder.

Comment: I can confirm this. Although I was updating the Router to the latest version in the package.json.. I was not updating the vendor folder by running the Gulp file.